# Building Apache Mesos cluster with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mesos, fig

we have an environment where docker containers are working together en they are managed by Apache mesos.
Now I saw this tutorial [part 1](http://container-solutions.com/continuous-delivery-with-docker-on-mesos-in-less-than-a-minute/) and [part 2](http://container-solutions.com/continuous-delivery-with-docker-on-mesos-in-less-than-a-minute-part-2/) which is working with fig. He is recommending to use the new docker compose.

I don't know fig and I don't know Docker compose. I know docker images, and containers and how they're working but nothing more.

I read the official documentation. It's nice to start multi-container environments (described in the dockercompose.yml. But can Docker Compose start other tools like apache Mesos? So actually: Can a Docker Compose file describe your whole configuration for application: so creating an apache mesos cluster with your Docker Containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can set up your whole cluster using docker compose if you wanted to.

Getting all the pieces working for your configuration could take some tweaking but here's an example of running a mesos/marathon cluster through a single dockercompose.yml:
[link](http://sebgoa.blogspot.com/2015/03/1-command-to-mesos-with-docker-compose.html)

The general steps:

1. Find dockerized versions of the services you want to run
2. Get them to run to spec
3. Link them together using docker compose.